# Help with installing and running ARI simulation

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic, ros-noetic, realsense

I am going through the installation steps for using the ARI simulation as seen [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/ARI/Tutorials/Installation/ARISimulation), and have successfully done so in the past without any issues. However, now I am experiencing the following errors after inserting the final `roslaunch ari_gazebo ari_gazebo.launch public_sim:=true` command for running the simulation:

```
xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.

resource not found: realsense_simulation

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_navigation/ari_2dnav
ROS path [2]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_simulation/ari_2dnav_gazebo
ROS path [3]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_robot/ari_bringup
ROS path [4]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_robot/ari_controller_configuration
ROS path [5]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_simulation/ari_controller_configuration_gazebo
ROS path [6]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_simulation/ari_gazebo
ROS path [7]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_navigation/ari_laser_sensors
ROS path [8]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_tutorials/ari_look_to_point
ROS path [9]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_navigation/ari_maps
ROS path [10]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_moveit_config
ROS path [11]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_tutorials/ari_moveit_tutorial
ROS path [12]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_navigation/ari_navigation
ROS path [13]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_navigation/ari_rgbd_sensors
ROS path [14]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_robot/ari_robot
ROS path [15]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_simulation/ari_simulation
ROS path [16]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_tutorials/ari_trajectory_controller
ROS path [17]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/aruco_ros/aruco
ROS path [18]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/aruco_ros/aruco_msgs
ROS path [19]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/aruco_ros/aruco_ros
ROS path [20]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_tutorials/ari_aruco_demo
ROS path [21]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/backward_ros
ROS path [22]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_control/controller_manager_msgs
ROS path [23]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ddynamic_reconfigure_python
ROS path [24]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/eband_local_planner
ROS path [25]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_dev
ROS path [26]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_msgs
ROS path [27]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins
ROS path [28]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros
ROS path [29]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_pkgs
ROS path [30]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_control/hardware_interface
ROS path [31]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_control/combined_robot_hw
ROS path [32]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_control/controller_interface
ROS path [33]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/actuator_state_controller
ROS path [34]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_control/controller_manager
ROS path [35]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_control/controller_manager_tests
ROS path [36]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_control/combined_robot_hw_tests
ROS path [37]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/diff_drive_controller
ROS path [38]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/force_torque_sensor_controller
ROS path [39]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/forward_command_controller
ROS path [40]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/effort_controllers
ROS path [41]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/four_wheel_steering_controller
ROS path [42]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/gripper_action_controller
ROS path [43]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/head_action
ROS path [44]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/hey5_description
ROS path [45]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/humanoid_msgs/humanoid_msgs
ROS path [46]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/humanoid_msgs/humanoid_nav_msgs
ROS path [47]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/imu_sensor_controller
ROS path [48]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_control/joint_limits_interface
ROS path [49]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_state_controller
ROS path [50]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_torque_sensor_state_controller
ROS path [51]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller
ROS path [52]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/teleop_tools/joy_teleop
ROS path [53]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/teleop_tools/key_teleop
ROS path [54]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/teleop_tools/mouse_teleop
ROS path [55]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/range_sensor_layer/navigation_layers
ROS path [56]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/openslam_gmapping
ROS path [57]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/slam_gmapping/gmapping
ROS path [58]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_behaviour_msgs
ROS path [59]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_statistics/pal_carbon_collector
ROS path [60]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_common_msgs
ROS path [61]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_control_msgs
ROS path [62]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_detection_msgs
ROS path [63]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_tutorials/ari_opencv_tutorial
ROS path [64]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_device_msgs
ROS path [65]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_gazebo_worlds
ROS path [66]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_gripper/pal_gripper
ROS path [67]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_gripper/pal_gripper_controller_configuration
ROS path [68]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_gripper/pal_gripper_controller_configuration_gazebo
ROS path [69]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_gripper/pal_gripper_gazebo
ROS path [70]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_hardware_interfaces
ROS path [71]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/mode_state_controller
ROS path [72]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_interaction_msgs
ROS path [73]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_tutorials/ari_say_something
ROS path [74]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_motion_model_msgs
ROS path [75]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_msgs
ROS path [76]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_multirobot_msgs
ROS path [77]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_gazebo_plugins
ROS path [78]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_navigation_cfg_public/pal_navigation_cfg_ari
ROS path [79]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_navigation_cfg_public/pal_navigation_cfg_omni_base
ROS path [80]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_navigation_cfg_public/pal_navigation_cfg_pmb2
ROS path [81]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_navigation_cfg_public/pal_navigation_cfg_pmb3
ROS path [82]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_navigation_cfg_public/pal_navigation_cfg_tiago
ROS path [83]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_navigation_cfg_public/pal_navigation_cfg_tiago_dual
ROS path [84]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_navigation_msgs
ROS path [85]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_navigation_sm
ROS path [86]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_gripper/pal_parallel_gripper_wrapper
ROS path [87]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_python
ROS path [88]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_simulation_msgs
ROS path [89]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_statistics/pal_statistics_msgs
ROS path [90]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_statistics/pal_statistics
ROS path [91]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/dynamic_introspection
ROS path [92]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_tablet_msgs
ROS path [93]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_video_recording_msgs
ROS path [94]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_vision_msgs
ROS path [95]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_visual_localization_msgs
ROS path [96]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_walking_msgs
ROS path [97]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_web_msgs
ROS path [98]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_msgs/pal_wifi_localization_msgs
ROS path [99]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_wsg_gripper/pal_wsg_gripper
ROS path [100]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_wsg_gripper/pal_wsg_gripper_controller_configuration
ROS path [101]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_wsg_gripper/pal_wsg_gripper_controller_configuration_gazebo
ROS path [102]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_wsg_gripper/pal_wsg_gripper_description
ROS path [103]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_wsg_gripper/pal_wsg_gripper_gazebo
ROS path [104]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/play_motion/play_motion_msgs
ROS path [105]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/position_controllers
ROS path [106]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/play_motion/play_motion
ROS path [107]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/range_sensor_layer/range_sensor_layer
ROS path [108]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/realsense/realsense2_camera
ROS path [109]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/realsense/realsense2_description
ROS path [110]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/realsense_gazebo_plugin
ROS path [111]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/robot_pose
ROS path [112]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/roboticsgroup_gazebo_plugins
ROS path [113]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_control/ros_control
ROS path [114]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/ros_controllers
ROS path [115]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_control/rqt_controller_manager
ROS path [116]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller
ROS path [117]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/rviz_plugin_covariance
ROS path [118]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/simple_grasping_action
ROS path [119]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/slam_gmapping/slam_gmapping
ROS path [120]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/range_sensor_layer/social_navigation_layers
ROS path [121]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/teleop_tools/teleop_tools
ROS path [122]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/teleop_tools/teleop_tools_msgs
ROS path [123]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/temperature_sensor_controller
ROS path [124]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/tf_lookup
ROS path [125]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_control/transmission_interface
ROS path [126]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control
ROS path [127]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_hardware_gazebo
ROS path [128]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/urdf_test
ROS path [129]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_robot/ari_description
ROS path [130]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/pal_gripper/pal_gripper_description
ROS path [131]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ros_controllers/velocity_controllers
ROS path [132]=/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/zbar_ros
ROS path [133]=/opt/ros/noetic/share

when processing file: /home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/realsense/realsense2_description/urdf/_d435.urdf.xacro
included from: /home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_robot/ari_description/urdf/head/head.urdf.xacro
included from: /home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_robot/ari_description/robots/ari.urdf.xacro
RLException: while processing /home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_simulation/ari_gazebo/launch/ari_gazebo.launch:
while processing /home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_simulation/ari_gazebo/launch/ari_spawn.launch:
while processing /home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_robot/ari_description/robots/upload.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [['rosrun', 'xacro', 'xacro', '--inorder', '/home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_robot/ari_description/robots/ari.urdf.xacro', 'robot_model:=v1', 'end_effector_right:=ari-hand', 'end_effector_left:=ari-hand', 'laser_model:=sick-571', 'camera_model_head:=raspi', 'front_fisheye_camera:=false', 'back_fisheye_camera:=false', 'has_thermal:=false', 'simulation:=true']] returned with code [2]. 

Param xml is <param name="robot_description" command="rosrun xacro xacro --inorder     '$(find ari_description)/robots/ari.urdf.xacro'     robot_model:=$(arg robot_model)     end_effector_right:=$(arg end_effector_right)     end_effector_left:=$(arg end_effector_left)     laser_model:=$(arg laser_model)     camera_model_head:=$(arg camera_model_head)     front_fisheye_camera:=$(arg front_fisheye_camera)     back_fisheye_camera:=$(arg back_fisheye_camera)     has_thermal:=$(arg has_thermal)     simulation:=$(arg simulation)     $(arg multi)"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I have tried running the simulation in both combinations of **Ubuntu 18 with melodic** and **Ubuntu 20 with noetic** in two different computers and both replicate the same issue. I have also tried to obtain additional information by running individual commands such as:

`rosrun xacro xacro /home/cs/ari_public_ws/src/ari_robot/ari_description/urdf/head/head.urdf.xacro`

but they produce the same error messages. I also focused on the installation of the `realsense` package as I am assuming the error is related to that, but without any success.

Has anyone experienced something similar or can replicate the installation and run the simulation without any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have 18.04 machine with Melodic I thought I'd help you (got greedy for bounty )

Seems main problem is that they removed the [this  package](https://github.com/pal-robotics/realsense_simulation) from melodic rosinstall:

```
- git: {local-name: realsense_simulation,    uri: 'https://github.com/pal-robotics/realsense_simulation.git', version: 'noetic-devel'}
```

the rosdep also didn't install multiple packages:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic --skip-keys="opencv2 opencv2-nonfree pal_laser_filters speed_limit_node sensor_to_cloud hokuyo_node libdw-dev python-graphitesend-pip python-statsd pal_filters pal_vo_server pal_usb_utils pal_pcl pal_pcl_points_throttle_and_filter pal_karto pal_local_joint_control camera_calibration_files pal_startup_msgs pal-orbbec-openni2 dummy_actuators_manager pal_local_planner gravity_compensation_controller current_limit_controller dynamic_footprint dynamixel_cpp tf_lookup opencv3 librealsense2-dev librealsense2-dkms hey5_transmissions ydlidar_ros_driver" -y


Error:

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
ari_bringup: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [twist_mux]
pal_navigation_cfg_pmb2: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [range_sensor_layer]
pal_navigation_cfg_pmb3: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [teb_local_planner]
pal_navigation_cfg_ari: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [teb_local_planner]
pal_gripper_description: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [urdf_test]
ari_moveit_tutorial: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_ros_planning_interface]
pal_navigation_cfg_tiago: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [range_sensor_layer]
ari_description: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [urdf_test]
realsense2_camera: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [librealsense2]
play_motion: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_ros_planning_interface]
ari_moveit_config: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_setup_assistant]
pal_navigation_cfg_omni_base: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [teb_local_planner]
realsense2_description: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [realsense_simulation]
pal_navigation_cfg_tiago_dual: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [range_sensor_layer]
four_wheel_steering_controller: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [urdf_geometry_parser]
```

So I installed them by hand:

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-twist-mux
sudo apt install ros-melodic-range-sensor-layer
sudo apt install ros-melodic-teb-local-planner
sudo apt install ros-melodic-urdf-test
sudo apt install ros-melodic-moveit-ros-planning-interface
sudo apt install ros-melodic-moveit-setup-assistant
sudo apt install ros-melodic-urdf-geometry-parser

sudo apt install ros-melodic-aruco-ros
sudo apt install ros-melodic-zbar-ros
sudo apt install ros-melodic-four-wheel-steering-msgs
```

Proof that I got it working:

[image]

I spent more time on this that I care to admit, but it was fun to play with old pakcages, maybe I would try to put this into Docker if I could, I doubt there are many people willing to tinker with EOL'ed sources/packages.
(Give me the bounty now!  )